# C++11 Error initializing struct inside a class (VS2013)

Tags: c++11, struct, initialization

I'm trying to run the following code using VS2013

```
#include<iostream>

enum class MyEnum : char {
    one, two, three
};

struct MyStruct {
    MyEnum me;
};

class MyClass{
    MyStruct ms{ MyEnum::one };
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "compiled";
}
```

but what I get is an

**error C2664: 'MyStruct::MyStruct(const MyStruct &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'MyEnum'to 'const MyStruct &'**

Compiling the same code on www.compileonline.com gives no errors. Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT: I would also like to mention that the following code compiles without errors.

```
...

int main() {
    MyStruct ms{ MyEnum::one };
    std::cout << "compiled";
}
```

Comment: "Am I missing something obvious here?" — no, but VS2013 apparently does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As n.m. said in a comment, it is likely that VS2013 is missing something.
As a temporary solution you could add a constructor to `MyStruct` that takes `MyEnum` as a parameter.

```
struct MyStruct {
  MyEnum me;

  MyStruct( MyEnum me ):
    me( me )
  {
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why initializing an instance of MyStruct without default constructor inside main gives no errors?